# Next.js Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) change revalidate time dynamically, trigger

Tags: reactjs, next.js, incremental-static-regeneration

I am using Next.js v12 and I running multiple pages with Incremental Static Regeneration.

I was just curious, instead of setting regenerate time (such as 10, 60), is there a way to trigger dynamically? (such as when backend api changes)

any other way other than hitting `revalidate: 60`?
Let me know !

Comment: Hi, I think you are looking for incremental on demand revalidation. Take a look at documentation here ```https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration```

Comment: Duh, I guess I didn't read the document carefully. THANK YOU!!!